# Android application crashing when updating from firebase-crashlytics 18.3.3 to 18.3.4

Tags: java, android, firebase, crashlytics

It seems that changing from
`'implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.3'`
to
`'implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.4'`
produces the following crashlog when the app initialises. Is there any dependencies I could be missing?

```
2023-02-14 23:43:27.026 13135-13135/ I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2023-02-14 23:43:27.052 13135-13135/ D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2023-02-14 23:43:27.054 13135-13135/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: , PID: 13135
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/annotations/concurrent/Background;
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar.getComponents(FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar.java:45)
        at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(ComponentRuntime.java:99)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(ComponentRuntime.java:46)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:437)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:271)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:256)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.annotations.concurrent.Background" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~s71FMMPQjbON5bHQXPtW2w==/-mUP09Nn8ZAhW8aCE_JxV8w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~s71FMMPQjbON5bHQXPtW2w==/-mUP09Nn8ZAhW8aCE_JxV8w==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~s71FMMPQjbON5bHQXPtW2w==/-mUP09Nn8ZAhW8aCE_JxV8w==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar.getComponents(FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar.java:45) 
        at com.google.firebase.tracing.ComponentMonitor.processRegistrar(ComponentMonitor.java:28) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.discoverComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:117) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(ComponentRuntime.java:99) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.<init>(ComponentRuntime.java:46) 
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$Builder.build(ComponentRuntime.java:387) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:437) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:303) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:271) 
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:256) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2404) 
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2374) 
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7422) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6939) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6710) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:247) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2053) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003) 
2023-02-14 23:43:28.677 13135-13147/ W/System: A resource failed to call close.
```

my module build.gradle has these dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.9.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'

    implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.26.0"

    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.1"
    implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-view:1.3.0-alpha02'

    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

and my project project build.gradle has the following dependencies

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

I am aware that I could just stay with version 18.3.3 but I am trying to understand why this crash is occuring.

Comment: `// When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies` -  Also from [firebase bom](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2023-02-10) release notes it seems support for `18.3.4` was added in latest version, Try using latest versions or compatible versions of library

Comment: @Nitish Oh I see, actually that did solve the issue, I upgraded the BoM version and removed the version of the firebase products and the application built and ran successfully

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Nitish, the BoM version did not support that version of Crashlytics. So I have updated the BoM version and removed the versions on the specific product version. My app build.gradle dependencies now look like this:

```
dependencies { ....
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics' ....
```

In line with the latest release by the time of writing taken from [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2023-02-10) and the app now builds and runs without crashing on start up. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more) also shows here that I did not have to specify the version for the specific firebase products.